# How to use an array as argument in createAction for @ngrx/store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I want to create an Action with an array as an argument, but this doesn't type check:

```js
export const action_organizations_available = createAction(
  CoreActionTypes.ORGANIZATIONS_AVAILABLE,
  props<Organization[]>()
);
```

I get `props(): "arrays are not allowed in action creators"`.
It works fine when the type is not an array.

Using `props<{ organizations: Organization[] }>` works, but I wonder if it's the best practice.

What is the best practice when expecting an array as an argument in an action?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to wrap it into an object:

```js
export const action_organizations_available = createAction(
  CoreActionTypes.ORGANIZATIONS_AVAILABLE,
  props<{ organizations: Organization[] }>()
);
```

EDIT: it's now a rule ["prefer-inline-action-props"](https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/prefer-inline-action-props.md) in the NgRx ESLint Plugin.

Comment: Thanks. Realized it actually sounds better to always wrap it into an object anyway. ngrx doc doesn't exhibit that, but it looks cleaner to me.

Comment: saved my life. by the way in the createReducer the param also need to be wrapped in object as you declare in the action creator